# Py4JJavaError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver while using pyspark in a conda environment

Tags: java, postgresql, pyspark, driver

I'm trying to load a spark dataframe into a postgresql table, I have added the latest postgresql jdbc driver into the spark.jars but I still get the error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o80.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
```

This is my code :

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark Purple Air") \
        .master("local") \
        .config("spark.jars", "/<location-jar-file>/postgresql-42.5.1.jar") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

```
list_df.select("api_version","data_time_stamp","sensor", "time_stamp").write.mode("overwrite").format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/purpleair_data") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver").option("dbtable", "purpleair") \
    .option("user", "postgres").option("password", "xxx").save()
```

I did find multiple related stack overflow links but all of them ended up getting solved when the jar file was configured to spark.jars which is what I have done and it still does not seem to work. I have installed pyspark in a conda environment and I'm running this code in a jupyter notebook. Any kind of help or workaround would really help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with spark.jars.packages (**org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1**):

with spark (pyspark):

```
self.spark_jars_packages = "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.246,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.3,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.0.0,org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1"

self.spark = (SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
appName("test-spark")
**.config("spark.jars.packages", self.spark_jars_packages)**
```

with delta:

```
self.packages = [
            "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.12.246,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0,org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.1"]

    self.spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(
        self.builder, extra_packages=self.packages).getOrCreate()
```